# how to create the instance of the dependent classes

Tags: java, spring

if class A is dependent on class B ,class Y will get injected into class X by the IoC.if we donot use spring ,how can we create the instance of the dependent classes

Comment: A and B, then Y and X, WTH?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use field injection, which is a best practice even when using something like Spring or CDI.